# Turkish character encoding in gedit

Tags: character-encoding, gedit, turkish

I have a Turkish written text but I have some strange characters for example:
ý instead of ı, Ý instead of İ etc... I tried to convert encoding to iso 8859-9 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a UNIX/Linux machine, try the following shell command:

```
you@somewhere:~$ file --mime yourfile.txt
```

It should output something like the snippet below, where `iso-8859-1` is the acutal character set your system assumes:

```
yourfile.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Now you can convert the file into some more flexible charset, like `UTF-8`:

```
you@somewhere:~$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 yourfile.txt > converted.txt
```

The above snippet specifies both, the charset to convert `-f`rom (which should equal the output of the `file` command) as well as the charset to convert `-t`o. The result of the conversion of `yourfile.txt` is then stored in `converted.txt`, which you should be able to open with `gedit`.

If that doesn't work, you may paste the output of the `file` command, as well as some real line of your file, in the comment section...